# Why the results of bash function depend on the scope the function is called from?

Tags: bash, function, loops

I have a problem with one of my bash scripts.
I have a variable and a function defined, something super simple:

```
RESULT='{"single":[],"theme":[],"imagesheet":[]}'

addResult() {
    type=$1
    filename=$2

    OP=".${type} += [\"${filename}\"]"
    RESULT=$(echo $RESULT | jq "$OP")
}
```

I call this `addResult` function and check the `$RESULT` variable and I can see that it is changed, and the json grows.

However, I also call this function from a loop:

```
grep -Rh "\.Image(\"" $MY_DIR | while read LINE; do

    addResult single "${LINE}"

done
```

When I check the variable from inside the loop, I can see that the entries are added to the json. However, immediately after the loop ends, the `$RESULT` variable loses all of the entries that were added inside the loop. What can I do, to make the changes made inside the loop remain?

EDIT:
Thanks to @marcolz I have modified my call to:

```
RESULT=$(grep -Rh "\.Image(\"" $MY_DIR | while read LINE; do check_imagesheets $LINE; done; echo $RESULT)
```

Unfortunately, the `check_imagesheets` function is quite large and it also contains quite some `echo` calls which pollute the final `echo $RESULT`. What other approach could I take to mitigate this issue?

Comment: As the variable is only set in the subshell that handles the commands after the pipe (`|`), either use the variable in that subshell, or pass the result afterwards.

Comment: @marcolz could you give me a tip on how can I do that?

Comment: for instance like: `OUTER_RES="$(grep -Rh "\.Image(\"" $MY_DIR | { while read LINE; do addResult single "${LINE}";done; echo $RESULT; } )"`

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. The code I pasted is an excerpt of what's going on in the loop. The whole body was far larger. I have moved the body into a function, cool, but inside there are plenty of echo's which I can't remove. This pollutes the last one and I end up with incorrect value.

Comment: `while read LINE; do
    addResult single "${LINE}";
done < <(grep -Rh '\.Image("' $MY_DIR)` You lose anything in the pipe when it's closed, i.e the copy of `RESULTS` that you're appending to.

Comment: thanks a lot guys. I have used what @123 proposed.

Answer (score 1):

An answer in the linked possible duplicate points to: [the Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

In your case you could use a named pipe or `shopt -s lastpipe` might work for you.